# Creating UIView on the fly with a UIViewController attached

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a MVC and I have a `CustomViewController` and a `CustomView`. I have all the properties set up so that when a `CustomViewController` is created the `view` attached to the controller automatically becomes a instance of `CutsomView`.

My question is, how do I set it up so that I have one `CustomViewController` and, lets say, 1 or 2 `CustomView`s that are assigned to the controller?

`MainViewController` adds the `CustomViewController` as a child view controller which then adds the `view` associated with `CustomViewController`. Now after this is done, is there a way to add a second `CustomView` with it being attached to the `CustomViewController`?

**Inside my `MainViewController`:**

[image]

Is this possible or do I just need to create a new `CustomViewController` for every CustomView I want?

The purpose of this is to have these views stacked on top of each other with different data  without calling a segue. Kinda like the way the new Facebook Paper app stacks their views.

Comment: ... create the second view in the `viewDidLoad` method ??? Whats the difficulty your having? what have you tried?

Comment: i added a bit more info in the question. @SimonMcLoughlin

Comment: 1. never take a screenshot of your code, place the code in the question and format it. 2. the last line is adding the view from `_customViewController` to the view in `MainViewController`. If _custom is a child of main, then this makes no sense. 3. If you want a second view, then again, create another view, I still don't understand the issue your facing

Comment: How do I make the `view` in `CustomViewController` visible after I create the controller then? The `CustomViewController` automatically creates the `CustomView` when I call `init`. @SimonMcLoughlin

Comment: if `_custom` is a `ViewController` with a `View`, then when it is added as a child `ViewController` the view will be visible where the viewController is placed on the screen. If it is not, then you have another issue. If you wanted to add a second view, then again inside the `viewDidLoad` of `_custom` create and add the view to the view belonging to `_custom`. When it gets added to main, both will be visible

Comment: yea if I comment out the `[self.view addSubview:_customViewController]` nothing happens (or rather the view doesn't become visible) @SimonMcLoughlin

Comment: ok sorry my bad, googled and your right you have to add the view as a subview. Ignore that comment. You can still create another view as a property of `_custom` and have it called the same way the view is now

Answer (score -1):

Make CustomView class as a Parent of CustomViewController :

e.g:-

```
- ParentViewController.h
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

 // You can put all common method here
- (IBAction) SetNavigationTitle:(NSString *)title;
@end


- LoginViewController
@interface LoginViewController : ParentViewController // in place of NSObject

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self SetNavigationTitle:@"User"];
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't think im understanding what you are saying.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to answer the question at all, doesn't look like you read it